# Using bootstrap for mobile only?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mobile

I have an existing site that is working well and didn't really want to "mess with it", however I do want to create a mobile / tablet version of the site.  My plan was to use bootstrap ONLY on the mobile version of the site to be responsive amongst tablets and phones (e.g. m.mysite.com and www.mysite.com)

Questions:
1) Are there any major issues with this approach?
2) What is the most reliable way for the code to determine if I should serve up the mobile/tablet version (m.mysite.com)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are two aproaches to handle this kind of problem.

Responsive site or separate site for mobile devices.

Both have pros and cons. In short with a responsive design you dont have to work on two seperate projects, but you can easily mess up your existing site.
With a seperate site you can easily limit the sites functionality to a simpler gui, but if you change something major you will have to do the job at two places.

In your case, if you want to leave the existing site alone, you should create a second site under the m. subdomain. 
In this case you only need to determine the device type on the www site and redirect them to the m site if they use a mobile device.

Comment: What is the most reliable way to determine the device type?